# How to connect bootstrap form to django form?

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-5

So, I need to have the styling of the bootstrap classes but actually have it connect to the django form in question.

```
``                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="last_name" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your last     name..." id="last_name" value="{{form.last_name.value}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>``
```

`{{form.last_name}}` on its own for example renders the form and actually makes it connect to the database, as it should. It looks ugly though and is thus not what I need. value="{{form.last_name}}" in the above codeblock renders the start of the input tag.

Comment: Have a look at [working with form templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates).

Comment: use a package called django-bootstrap-v5 or something like that. These packages offer template tags or filters to style form elements.